# Curl using public key authentication instead of password and not asking for fingerprint verification

Tags: centos, curl, sftp

I have a following command, where I am trying to upload a file remote host using curl and sftp.

```
curl -v -k --user user1:password -T /home/user1/file1.txt sftp://hostname/home/user1/
```

When I run this I get.

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 1.2.3.4.5...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to hostname1 (1.2.3.4.5) port 22 (#0)
* User: user1
* Authentication using SSH public key file
* Completed public key authentication
* Authentication complete
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host hostname1 left intact
```

I have two questions here:

- When I have specified password why it attempted to use public key
  authentication.
- How it even got succeeded, both are new servers and
  never communicated to each other before, so should I receive a prompt
  to verify fingerprint?

In actual, I completely want to avoid public key authentication and use password due to automation issues of fingerprint changes.

Answer (score -1):

remove "-k" in the command line

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.